# serial.parseInt() returns a 0 value on its own

Tags: arduino, serial-port

I am trying to read some integers from serial, so I used Serial.parseInt() to read two values(0 or 1), the thing is the code runs perfectly for the first time, but then the serial start reading the value 0 on its own, without me sending anything, here is part of the code I am using:

```cpp
while (!Serial.available()) {}
A = Serial.parseInt();
Serial.println(A);
if (A == 1) {
  Book = "";
  Serial.println("add tag");
  while (Book == "") {
    delay(2000);
    Book = tagB();
  }
  Serial.println(Book);
  sendToE1("", Book);
  delay(2000);
}
}
}
```

Comment: there are 'invisible' line ending characters to read.

Answer (score 3):

You probably need to set the monitor to "No line ending".

Answer (score 2):

`Serial.parseInt` returns `0` when it times out with none or invalid characters received.

As you're loop is waiting for available data befor you call `Serial.parseInt` the only explanation is that you're sending something else but numbers. Most likely a linefeed or carriage return from your terminal program or a println function...

You should probably call `Serial.peek` to check if the next byte is a number befor you call `Serial.parseInt`. If you know for sure that you did not send anything but that single integer and some non-numeric character you can also clear the input buffer befor parsing a possible next integer.

But if you're sending an integer and a termination character you might as well just not use `Serial.parseInt`. Read your data into an array until you receive the termination character. Then convert your data to an integer yourself.

Using `Serial.parseInt` only makes sense if you know you're about to receive an integer representation within a certain time interval.